# Implementing seek/scrubbing preview

Tags: android, exoplayer

To implement a smooth seek preview ([video example](https://yadi.sk/i/Wp9BxMdBUhI1Nw)), it seems to me there are several methods:

1. Preprocess with frame extraction (too much RAM usage, need time to load)
2. Playing with flexible playback speed while seeking (need to make reverse version of source video)

Is there an optimal technique for showing previews using ExoPlayer?

Answer (score 1):

The video seek 'frames' that you see with an online video stream are generally actually discrete images that are contained in a separate thumbnail track in the media stream.

The thumbnail track is created in advance, generally on the server side, and included in the container in the video stream. It will have a thumbnail image, for example, every minute in the video, and when you hover or seek along the timeline the player displays this image, rather than trying to decode the video at that point.

If you need greater granularity you can have more thumbnails - e.g. every 10, 20, 30 seconds as needed, with the caveat that it increases the size of the thumbnail track. The player will typically download the thumbnail track in advance.

The video example you shared looks more like a video editor use case. That would be probably a separate solution type if this is your use case. It would likely be better to look at some open source online video editors as a starting point and work from there - an example that appears to be active at the time of writing:

- https://github.com/moviemasher/moviemasher.js

Comment: Yep, it's video editor use case. Unfortunately, I haven't found any opensource implementation, even method how cant it be done, but some apps from the Play Store have a similar feature. Maybe here are ExoPlayer limitations and i have to switch to another player API.